# SQL: Feeding SELECT output to LIKE

Tags: sql, regex, database, oracle

Problem:

```
select STR1 from T1 where STR2 = 'NAME1'
```

In the above query STR1 can be in form {ABC, ABC_1, ABC_2,..., MNO, XYZ, XYZ_1...}.

So let suppose I have following output

```
ABC_1
MNO
XYZ
```

Now I want to extract all those matching STR1 that include the part before **_#**. For example the expected output for the example dataset above is:

```
ABC
ABC_1
ABC_2

MNO

XYZ
XYZ_1
```

Note that STR2 is always unique per STR1.

Code wise I imagine some thing like following:

```
SELECT 
    STR1 
FROM 
    T1 
WHERE
    STR1 
LIKE '% (truncate_underscore_part(select STR1 from T1 where STR2 = 'NAME1')) %'
```

Any idea?

First solution:

```
select t1.str1
  from (
  select case when instr( str1, '_' ) > 0
                then substr( str1, 1, instr( str1, '_' ) - 1 )
              else str1
         end prefix
    from t1 where str2 = 'NAME1'
) prefix_list,
  t1
  where t1.str1 like prefix || '%'
```

Comment: Are you using oracle, or mySql?

Comment: Your example of the output from the first query shows only items with no underscore, but do I understand from your description that the first list could include 'ABC_1', etc., as well, and you want to strip the _# portion of the string before proceeding with the matching?

Comment: Why is this tagged as both Oracle and MySQL???

Comment: I don't quite get what you mean. If I understand you correctly you have a table with fields in the format `something` and `something_n`. Given what input would you like what output exactly?

Comment: @MichaelFredrickson I am using oracle.

Comment: @DaveCosta Good catch. Yes your assumption is right. the result in first case may include the *_#.

Comment: @LovelyVirus are you sure that ABC and ABC_2 should be returned too? the first list of items has ABC_1 (not ABC), and I'm not sure if it's a typo or expected behaviour

Comment: Yes ABC and ABC_2 should be returned. The example output in first case is also true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with prefix_list as (
  select regexp_substr( str1, '^[A-Z]*' ) prefix from t1 where str2 = 'NAME1'
)
select t1.str1 from t1 join prefix_list
        on t1.str1 = prefix_list.prefix
           or regexp_like( t1.str1, prefix_list.prefix||'_[0-9]' )
```

To do it without the regexp functions (for older Oracle versions), it depends a bit on how much you want to validate the format of the strings.

```
select t1.str1
  from (
  select case when instr( str1, '_' ) > 0
                then substr( str1, 1, instr( str1, '_' ) - 1 )
              else str1
         end prefix
    from t1 where str2 = 'NAME1'
) prefix_list,
  t1
where t1.str1 = prefix
   or t2.str1 like prefix || '\__' escape '\'
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't do TOAD.  Try SQLPlus or SQL Developer.

Comment: It's oracle error regardless of TOAD, sqlplus. I tried on both.

Comment: What version of Oracle are you on?

Comment: For this particular database: Oracle9i Enterprise Edition Release 9.2.0.8.0.

Comment: Ah, I think the regexp_* functions were introduced in 10.

Comment: Thanks for the latest solution. With slight modificaiton this worked as I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is with a self-join.

Here's an example for MySQL:

```
SELECT t2.str1
FROM t1 
  INNER JOIN T1 as t2 on (t2.str1 = t1.str1 OR t2.str1 LIKE CONCAT(t1.str1,'\_%'))
WHERE t1.STR2 = 'NAME1'
```

And here's an attempt to translate that to Oracle syntax:

```
SELECT t2.str1
FROM t1 
  INNER JOIN T1 as t2 on (t2.str1 = t1.str1 OR t2.str1 LIKE t1.str1 || '\_%')
WHERE t1.STR2 = 'NAME1'
```

Comment: My answer was for MySQL since your question was originally tagged as MySQL. I'll try to translate it to Oracle.

Comment: Sorry for the tags. Regardless the same error again (cursor on 'as').

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, I would use

```
where regexp_like(str1, '[A-Z]{3}(_[0-9]+)?')
```